# Rails select and order

Tags: ruby-on-rails, associations

I am trying to select a counting of columns from the association and it doesn't seem to work. Here's my code:

> > ```
> > scope :search, lambda { |search, order_syntax|
> >     select("*, COUNT(payment_notifications.p_type) AS number_of_objects")
> >     {
> >       :conditions =>
> >       ['items.title LIKE ? OR items.desc LIKE ? OR taggings.context LIKE ?', "%#{search}%", "%#{search}%", "%#{search}%"],
> >       :include => [:taggings, :payment_notifications, :user],
> >       :order => 'number_of_objects'
> >     }
> >   }
> > ```

What I am trying to achieve is:
I want to order by the number of purchases. So, let's say this is my payment_notifications table:

> > item_id | p_type
> >
> > 2       | 'payment'
> >
> > 2       | 'payment'
> >
> > 6       | 'payment'
> >
> > 2       | 'payment'
> >
> > 3       | 'payment'
> >
> > 6       | 'payment'
> >
> > nil        | 'withdrawal'

The order should be like:
2
6
3

Hope you understand.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What doesn't work? Also, are you on Rails 2 or 3?

Comment: Rails 3. It gives an error 'unknown column number_of_objects'. I think I need a whole new code because I don't think that mine even does what I need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found my solution. needed to use the counter cache. Thanks everyone!

Answer (score 0):

You should also include itme_id in order block

```
:order => 'item_id,number_of_objects'
```

Comment: The code doesn't work, I think I need a whole new code because mine doesn't even do what I need.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, you should use a normal method instead of a scope, as the query is fairly complex, and the result will be exactly the same (just easier to format).

Secondly, I'm not sure why you have a parameter "order_syntax" in that lambda when you're not using it anywhere.

Here's what I would suggest (using the new Active Record chaining syntax). I haven't tested it, but it should work if I understood your original query.

```
def search(term)
  select("*, COUNT(payment_notifications.p_type) AS number_of_objects").
    where('items.title LIKE ? OR items.desc LIKE ? OR taggings.context LIKE ?', "%#{term}%", "%#{term}%", "%#{term}%").
      includes(:taggings, :payment_notifications, :user).
        order('number_of_objects')
end
```

Comment: Same error:

SQLite3::SQLException: no such column: number_of_objects: SELECT  DISTINCT "items".id FROM "items" LEFT OUTER JOIN "taggings" ON "taggings"."taggable_id" = "items"."id" AND "taggings"."taggable_type" = 'Item' LEFT OUTER JOIN "payment_notifications" ON "payment_notifications"."item_id" = "items"."id" LEFT OUTER JOIN "users" ON "users"."id" = "items"."user_id" WHERE "items"."visible" = 't' AND (items.title LIKE '%%' OR items.desc LIKE '%%' OR taggings.context LIKE '%%') ORDER BY number_of_objects LIMIT 10 OFFSET 0